# pgAdmin 4.1:Restoring backup failed but window's always open

Tags: postgresql, backup, restore, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

few days ago I tried to restore a Postgres backup using pgAdmin 4.1. 
The restore process failed, so I did it again outside the tool, via command line. 
Now the problem is that a  small blue window is still displaying at the right-down corner of my pgAdmin, remembering me that restoring failed with exit code -1, and there is no way to dismiss it, even closing and restarting program, processes, windows, neither the "reset layout" command could help me...
Does someone know how to kill that popup window?
Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL command to stop job in pgAdmin 4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679353/sql-command-to-stop-job-in-pgadmin-4)

Comment: I have the same error but I noticed that despite the _exit code 1_, the restore is successful. Try to check if the restore has done regardless of the error.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone is lookig for a solution I found the answer in the link below, but be careful because in my case it erased all my existing conenctions but the default one, besides that it works perfectly:

[SQL command to stop job in pgAdmin 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40679353/sql-command-to-stop-job-in-pgadmin-4?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: This would have been better to leave as a comment and have others mark this as duplicate.

Answer (score -1):

Click on the "Click here for details." link in the blue box, and then dismiss the resulting dialog box with the X at top right. The blue box will disappear.

This was asked a while ago, but it took me a while to find the answer so I'm posting.