# SQL command to stop job in pgAdmin 4

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgadmin-4

I have a Postgres 9.6 installation on a developer pc and a restore seems to have failed. Even after reinstalling (remove Postgres and PgAdmin completely, incl. database and installed new version) the boxes are popping up (even though these tables do not even exist anymore). How to remove these scheduled jobs? Is there an SQL statement to stop these?

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion: because PgAdmin4 is a web-based application actually, try to find where it stores its cookies and other files and clean it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found solution: This problem is related to the `pgadmin.db`. Just remove the file and the error is gone (but you also have to reenter all passwords etc.). The problem is that this file is not removed when uninstalling postgres/pgadmin. It can be found in

> C:\Users\YourUsername\AppData\Roaming\pgAdmin

Comment: hey bro, how can I restored dataase and servers.  I 'm deleted pgadmin.db then deleted all servers and databases ,

Answer (score 5):

another solution is to open the file pgadmin.db with SQLite Manager (A firefox extension) and remove all rows in the table process

Comment: This post isn't an actual attempt at answering the question. Please note [StackOverflow doesn't work like a discussion forum](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), it is a Q&A site where every post is either a question or an answer to a question. Posts can also have [comments](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) - small sentences like this one - that can be used to critique or request clarification from an author. This should be either a comment or a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)

Comment: Hmm, I think this is an answer. It seems to solve the problem, too. ;-)

Comment: I'm on a Macintosh.  pgadmin.db is nowhere to be found (well, my Unix find command is still running, but not via Mac search).  I tried a complete uninstall & reinstall, and my zombie restore process was waiting for me when I re-opened my freshly installed pgAdmin.  Any ideas?